# Css Background overlay affecting the heading text

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.bg-overlay{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        z-index:0;
    }
    #popular-packages{
        position: relative;
        min-height:900px;
        background: url('../../photos/bg/pack-bg.jpg');
        color:white;
    }
    #popular-packages .heading{
        padding-top:15vh;
    }
    #popular-packages .heading h2{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size:40px;
        z-index:2;
    }
    #popular-packages .heading h4{
        font-size:20px;
        line-height: 36px;
    }
    .single-package-item .image-section{
        position: relative;
    }
    .single-package-item .image-section img{
        width:100%;
    }
    .single-package-item .package-cost{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        background-color: #F9676B;
        padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    .single-package-item h5{
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top:25px;
    }
    .single-package-item p{
        font-size:15px;
    }
    .single-package-item .read-more{
        color:#f9676b;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .single-package-item .read-more .fa-arrow-right{
        font-size:12px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        position: relative;
        top:-2px;
    }
    .single-package-item .read-more:hover .fa-arrow-right{
        margin-left:10px;
    }
    .more-package{
        background-color: #f9676b;
        width:200px;
        padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
        margin:auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition:0.5s;
    }
```

```html
     <section id="popular-packages">
                <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="heading text-center mb-5">
                        <h2>POPULAR PACKAGES</h2>
                        <h4>TRAVEL EXPRESS PROVIDE</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="single-package-item">
                                <div class="image-section">
                                    <img src="photos/package/pack-1.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="package-cost">$3000</div>
                                </div>
                                <h5>AMERICA- 5 Days, 4 Nights</h5>
                                <p>
                                    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, 
                                    but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by
                                </p>
                                <div class="read-more">  
                                    Read More  <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="single-package-item">
                                <div class="image-section">
                                    <img src="photos/package/pack-2.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="package-cost">$4000</div>
                                </div>
                                <h5>Thailand- 4 Days, 3 Nights</h5>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet modi 
                                    inventore voluptatum molestiae assumenda
                                </p>
                                <div class="read-more">
                                    Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="single-package-item">
                                <div class="image-section">
                                    <img src="photos/package/pack-3.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="package-cost">$4000</div>
                                </div>
                                <h5>Thailand- 4 Days, 3 Nights</h5>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet modi 
                                    inventore voluptatum molestiae assumenda
                                </p>
                                <div class="read-more">
                                    Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="more-package btn-hover-white text-center my-5">
                        MORE PACKAGE
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

I have added an black overlay on this section and dont know why but it is affecting all the heading texts leaving the row elements. I can solve it by making everything the children div of bg-overlay. But on doing that min-height does not work. I want to preserve the min-height also making heading text have normal color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Add this CSS.**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want `bg-overlay` behind `container`? If yes you have to apply some css in `container` class. add below css in `container` class.

```
position:relative
z-index:1
```

Answer (score 0):

in `.single-package-item .package-cost` instead `bottom:0` use `top:0` like this:

```
 .single-package-item .package-cost {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #F9676B;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
```

the full code here:

```css
 .bg-overlay {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   z-index: 0;
  }
  
  #popular-packages {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 900px;
   background: url('../../photos/bg/pack-bg.jpg');
   color: white;
  }
  
  #popular-packages .heading {
   padding-top: 15vh;
  }
  
  #popular-packages .heading h2 {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-weight: 800;
   font-size: 40px;
   z-index: 2;
  }
  
  #popular-packages .heading h4 {
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 36px;
  }
  
  .single-package-item .image-section {
   position: relative;
   vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .single-package-item .image-section img {
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .single-package-item .package-cost {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   background-color: #F9676B;
   padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
   font-weight: 800;
  }
  
  .single-package-item h5 {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   margin-top: 25px;
  }
  
  .single-package-item p {
   font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  .single-package-item .read-more {
   color: #f9676b;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .single-package-item .read-more .fa-arrow-right {
   font-size: 12px;
   transition: 0.5s;
   position: relative;
   top: -2px;
  }
  
  .single-package-item .read-more:hover .fa-arrow-right {
   margin-left: 10px;
  }
  
  .more-package {
   background-color: #f9676b;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<section id="popular-packages">
    <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="heading text-center mb-5">
    <h2>POPULAR PACKAGES</h2>
    <h4>TRAVEL EXPRESS PROVIDE</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="single-package-item">
      <div class="image-section">
       <img src="photos/package/pack-1.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="package-cost">$3000</div>
      </div>
      <h5>AMERICA- 5 Days, 4 Nights</h5>
      <p>
       There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by
      </p>
      <div class="read-more">
       Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="single-package-item">
      <div class="image-section">
       <img src="photos/package/pack-2.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="package-cost">$4000</div>
      </div>
      <h5>Thailand- 4 Days, 3 Nights</h5>
      <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet modi inventore voluptatum molestiae assumenda
      </p>
      <div class="read-more">
       Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="single-package-item">
      <div class="image-section">
       <img src="photos/package/pack-3.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="package-cost">$4000</div>
      </div>
      <h5>Thailand- 4 Days, 3 Nights</h5>
      <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet modi inventore voluptatum molestiae assumenda
      </p>
      <div class="read-more">
       Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="more-package btn-hover-white text-center my-5">
    MORE PACKAGE
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```